# Updating query with comparison between string and varchar(max)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

i have an updating query like this:

```
 public void Update_Download(string _url){
            Data.Connect();
            using (Data.connexion)
            {

                string queryString = "update Fichier set Last_download=@last , Downloads_count= Downloads_count + 1  where Url = @url ";


                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Data.connexion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", _url);
                try
                {
                  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 }
                catch { }

                }
         }


    }
}
```

the string connection :

```
public static SqlConnection connexion;


        public static bool  Connect()
        {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder["Initial Catalog"] = "Upload";
                builder["Data Source"] = "bd";
                builder["integrated Security"] = true;
                string connexionString = builder.ConnectionString;
                connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);
                try { connexion.Open(); return true; }
                catch { return false; }

        }
        public static  void Disconnect()
        {
            if (connexion != null) connexion.Close();
            connexion = null;
        }
```

the query is executing without exception but nothing is changed in table. the type of the attribute `Url` is varchar(Max) and the DBMS is `Sql Server`.

So what is the problem? how can i correct my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `ExecuteReader` command. Change that to this:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now, on top of that, I want to offer some advice. Consider the following modification of your current code:

```
public void Update_Download(string _url)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connexion = Data.Connect())
        {
            string queryString = "update Fichier set Last_download=@last , Downloads_count= Downloads_count + 1  where Url = @url ";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connexion))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", _url);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

and consider having `Data.Connect()` return a `new SqlConnection(...)` because you want to follow that procedure. When you need a new connection, get one using the `new` operation, and let SQL Server manage the pooling. **Never share connections.**

I'm not sure you **are sharing connection**, this is just an observation.

Comment: @Lamloumi, and so if that's the case, the `WHERE` clause is your problem. I can't tell you why the `url` field doesn't match the value in `@url`, that's something you'll have to debug.

Comment: @Lamloumi, what I'm trying to say is that if you're using `ExecuteNonQuery` in place of `ExecuteReader`, **in your original code**, and it's not updating the database then the `WHERE` clause is keeping any records from being affected. There's not much I can do here to help because you need to determine why the value of `_url` doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: i changed to `ExecuteReader` to `ExecuteNonQuery` . for the value of `_url` it is an url of a file and it is correct because i succed to download it and the value of `_url` in debugging  is true

Comment: @Lamloumi, but is there a record in `Fichier` with that URL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31340/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-michael-perrenoud)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you can see in MSDN at this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.80).aspx

> ExecuteNonQuery : Executes commands such as Transact-SQL INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and SET statements.

So try to use this method, this should work !

Comment: Have you used the code given by Michael Perrenoud ? With the "Using" to create SQLCOnnection ?

Comment: ok, I see that you are not doing anything in you catch. Maybe you are getting an exception and you cannot see it. To comfirm that, in Vs Studio, Press CTRL+ALT+e, and check "Thrown" beside Common Language Runtime Exceptions then OK. It should show you all the exceptions occurring in you applications (as long as you are running in Debug Mode)